# How can I split a comma delimited string into an array and again split that array by colon?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a string, which is comma separated. I have used explode to separate it by comma, which gives me result as array. In that array i have data which needs to be separated by `:`. How can I achieve this? Below is the string and the output.

String:

```
$ing= 'coconut water :3-4 cups, coconut flesh : ½ cup, tea :4 tablespoon, Ice cubes :24-32, Lemon juice :4 tablespoon, Honey :8 tablespoon'
$output = explode(',', $ing);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => coconut water :3-4 cups 
    [1] => coconut flesh : ½ cup 
    [2] => tea :4 tablespoon 
    [3] => Ice cubes :24-32 
    [4] => Lemon juice :4 tablespoon 
    [5] => Honey :8 tablespoon )
```

Now, I want separate coconut water :3-4 cups by colon.

```
$ing= 'coconut water :3-4 cups, coconut flesh : ½ cup, tea :4 tablespoon, Ice cubes :24-32, Lemon juice :4 tablespoon, Honey :8 tablespoon'
$output1 = explode(',', $ing);
$output=array();
foreach($output1 as $item){
  $output[]=explode(':', $item);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => coconut water 
        [1] => 3-4 cups
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
coconut flesh 
        [1] =>  ½ cup
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
tea 
        [1] => 4 tablespoon
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
Ice cubes 
        [1] => 24-32
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
Lemon juice 
        [1] => 4 tablespoon
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
 Honey 
        [1] => 8 tablespoon
    )

)
```

Desired Output:

```
<tr>
  <td>coconut water </td>
  <td>3-4 cups</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>coconut flesh</td>
  <td>½ cup</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>tea </td>
  <td>4 tablespoon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ice cubes</td>
  <td>24-32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lemon juice</td>
  <td>4 tablespoon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Honey</td>
  <td>8 tablespoon</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$output = explode(',', $ing); array_walk($output, function (&$value) { $value = explode(':', $value); });`

Comment: Do you want the final result to all be in a one dimensional array or can array[0] be an array after the second explode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
$ing= 'coconut water :3-4 cups, coconut flesh : ½ cup, tea :4 tablespoon, Ice cubes :24-32, Lemon juice :4 tablespoon, Honey :8 tablespoon'
$output1 = explode(',', $ing);
$output=array();
foreach($output1 as $item){
    $output[]=explode(':', $item);
}
```

To display segments:

```
foreach($output as $row){
   //insert a new row here:
   echo '<tr>';
      //fill cells in row:
      echo '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';
   //close the row:
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `$output = []`?

Comment: @BenMansley Where do you mean?

Comment: Declaration, `$output = array()`

Comment: @BenMansley Thanks, `$output=[];` works as of `php 5.4`

Comment: How can i show this separated data in two columns of table. ie in <td></td>.I tried echo but this is giving me Array to string conversion error.@ Ormoz

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one .. This might work :)**

```
$ing= 'coconut water :3-4 cups, coconut flesh : ½ cup, tea :4 tablespoon, Ice cubes :24-32, Lemon juice :4 tablespoon, Honey :8 tablespoon';
$output = explode(',', $ing);

function getBetween($content,$start,$end) {
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1])){

        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];

    }
    return '';
}


    foreach ($output as $value) {
        # code...

            $value = $value.'_!!_';
            $data = getBetween($value,':','_!!_');
            echo $data = str_replace('_!!_','',$data);
            echo '<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ing = 'coconut water :3-4 cups, coconut flesh : ½ cup, tea :4 tablespoon, Ice cubes :24-32, Lemon juice :4 tablespoon, Honey :8 tablespoon';

$lines = explode( ',', $ing );

foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    $item = explode( ':', $line );
    $tablerow[] = '<td>' . $item[0] . '</td><td>' . $item[1] . '</td>';
}

echo '<table><tr>' . implode( '</tr><tr>', $tablerow ) . '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you iterate over the array you have after using explode, you also can use explode to separate the values (values of your array) by colon.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What is the problem with my answer? I did describe exactly the same as the accepted solution does, except I did not provide source code.